# Finding the integer solutions of the equation $3\sqrt {x + y} + 2\sqrt {8 - x} + \sqrt {6 - y} = 14$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

$
3\sqrt {x + y}  + 2\sqrt {8 - x}  + \sqrt {6 - y}  = 14
$ .

I already solved this using the  Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and got $x=4$ and $y=5$. But I'm sure there is a prettier, simpler solution to this and I was wondering if anyone could suggest one.

Comment: Well, the left side is a sum of non-negative real numbers, so the number of possibilities is not that big.

Comment: how did you solve it using cauchy-schwarz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality goes like this:

$LHS \leq \sqrt{3^2+2^2+1^2}\cdot \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{x+y}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{8-x}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{6-y}\right)^2}=14=RHS$.

Thus you have equality when $\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x+y}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{8-x}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6-y}} \to x=4,y=5$.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you wrote, we can deduct the following:
$$x+y\geq 0$$
$$8-x\geq 0 $$
$$6-y \geq 0$$ As a result, $$14 \geq x+y\geq 0$$
You also know that $x+y$ is a square. Therefore, you have only 4 squares that satisfy this double inequality: $$ 0, 1, 4, 9$
You can quickly eliminate 0, 1 as options because it would to 2 irrationals.

As far as $4$, that'd generate $ (0,4),(4,0),(1,3),(3,1) $ and $(2,2)$ . Clearly none of them satisfies your equation.

$9$ generates $(3,6),(6,3),(4,5)$and$ (5,4)$. We cannot take into consideration $(0,9),(9,0)$ because $x\leq8$ and $y \leq 6$.

From here, given the fact that $8-x$ and $6-y$ must be perfect squares, it can be deducted the only couple that satisfies your equation is $(4,5)$.

Comment: It's not immediate that $x+y$, $8-x$, and $6-y$ are squares. You have to rule out the possibility that you can add two or three irrational square roots, and get an integer.

Comment: @Gerry, Ok. How would you propose to do that?

Comment: It takes a bit of work to prove that a sum of irrational square roots can't be rational. You could ask that as a new question, but first search this website to see whether it hasn't already been asked and answered here before.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial solution so that we get answer in integer

8 - x and 6 - y are under the root so x <8 and y <6 , for making 6 - y to be perfect square y=2 or 5. and similarly x=4 or 7.

Now x+y is also under the root so x+y has to be perfect square. So we get two pairs of (x, y)=(7,2) and (2,5) but (7,2) will not satisfy the equation so ur answer is x=4, y=5.

Comment: It isn't simplest way of solving this ?

Comment: But how do you know that $x+y$, $8-x$, and $6-y$ are perfect squares? Just being under a square root sign doesn't make a number a perfect square.

Comment: for simplicity , what do u do to avoid roots, make the number under the roots to be perfect square so roots will be cancelled

Comment: If u suppose them to be perfect square , then only u can get into integers

Comment: If we were only interested in simplicity, we could solve all kinds of difficult problems. But we are interested in truth, as well as simplicity, so we can't make unfounded assumptions. And please write English, not texting-speak.

Comment: I initially said that this is a trivial solution